# Unable to build ios app for simulator using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am currently want to create a debug simulator build using xcodebuild command rather than xcode IDE.

however, I always see a "debug-iphoneos" folder is generated, which is for the real device. I expected the simulator output folder "Debug-iphonesimulator"

Can anyone take a look at my script and suggest why the script is not working for simulator?

```
xcodebuild -scheme "TestApp" -configuration "Debug" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest' -workspace TestApp.xcworkspace clean archive -archivePath build/TestApp PROVISIONING_PROFILE="$provisioningUUID" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$codeSignIdentity"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I can run successfully as below:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator9.3 -workspace "$app.xcworkspace" -scheme "$scheme" -configuration "Debug"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run the following instead:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator9.1 -workspace [name].xcworkspace -scheme [targetName or ProjectName] ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"
```

where `iphonesimulator9.1` depends on which iPhone Simulator you installed.

Comment: now i get this error:   No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s).

Comment: You can override by adding `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"`. Updated the answer.

Comment: now this:  warning: no rule to process file '/Users/xxx/Documents/git_folder/xxx/Sources/xxxx/README.md' of type net.daringfireball.markdown for architecture i386
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 9.2'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.

Comment: I also try below,  get the same error:  xcodebuild -scheme "$scheme" -configuration "Debug" -arch i386 -sdk "iphonesimulator9.2" -workspace $app.xcworkspace clean archive -archivePath build/$app PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$provisioningUUID CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$codeSignIdentity" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"